# Find measure of $\mu(\mathbb{Q} \cup [0, 1])$ on half-opened intervals semiring.

Tags: measure-theory, solution-verification

Consider half-opened intervals semiring with classic Lebesgue measure $\mu([a, b)) = b - a$. We want to know whether the measure of $\mu(\mathbb{Q}\cap[0,1])$ is zero.

My attempt: we can prove that this measure is $\sigma$-additive. Now we can consider $\mu(\mathbb{Q}\cap[0, 1]) \le \bigcup_{i} \mu\left(\Big[q_i, q_i + \dfrac{\varepsilon}{2^i}\Big)\right) = \varepsilon$. Hence it's zero.

But why can't we do the same for irrationals numbers? It's measure of course should be unit (since $\mu(\mathbb{I}) + \mu(\mathbb{Q}) = 1$). Doesn't these sequence of half-opened cover all irrationals on $[0, 1]$?

Answer (score 1):

$\mu (\cup_i A_i) \leq \sum_i \mu (A_i)$ is valid only for countable families $(A_i)$. In the case of irrationals you will get an uncountable union so the proof fails.

Comment: I understand. But does there any $a \in \mathbb{I} \cap [0, 1]$ : $a \notin \bigcup_i \Big[r_i, r_i + \dfrac{\varepsilon}{2^i}\Big)$?

Comment: No, all irrationals belong to this union, but you get stuck after this. @openspace